# could be with past, present and future

Tags: tense

is it ok to use could be with past, present and future actions.

the bridge **could be** removed **yesterday** but they decided to do it today.

the bridge **could be** removed **today** .

There are chances that the bridge **could be** removed **tomorrow** by this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine with non-past, but it doesn't work with past. The first needs to be *could have been removed*.

Note that 2 unambiguously refers to the part of today starting from  now: if you're referring to earlier today, that also needs to be *could have been removed*.

Comment: Is this ok, "There are chances that the bridge could be removed tomorrow by this time".

Comment: Yes, except that _there are chances_ is not idiomatic: _there is a chance that..._  Your second and third examples use the same tense, the non-past (often misleadingly referred to as the "present"), which was why I said it was fine with the non-past.

Comment: so "could have been" used for past only, not for non-past.

Comment: No. One use of it is for (possibly realisable) conditions in the pas: _They could have seen him yesterday: they didn't tell me_. Another use of it is for an _irrealis_ (or _counterfactual_ - something that did not/is not going to happen) in any tense: _I could have been rich if my company hadn't failed_ might be referring to a past or to a present or future possibility, but in any case the speaker knows that it can't happen.